# How to use test suite in NUnit 3

Tags: c#, nunit, assert, nunit-3.0

I'm using NUnit 3 and having problems using test suites. I saw this [Documentation page](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=suite&r=2.4.4), but it's for the old version and I can't find anything in the new documentation.

This does not work, because [Suite] is invalid.

```
[Suite]
public static IEnumerable Suite
{
  get
  {
    ArrayList suite = new ArrayList();
    suite.Add(typeof(OneTestCase));
    suite.Add(typeof(AssemblyTests));
    suite.Add(typeof(NoNamespaceTestFixture));
    return suite;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SuiteAttribute` [has been removed from NUnit 3](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/release-notes/breaking-changes.html) (see the *Attributes* table).

You should instead use the expanded [Test Selection Language](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/running-tests/Test-Selection-Language.html) in the command line runner to control the groups of tests you want to run, or alternatively structure your tests differently.

Comment: ok, thanks :) !
But all that stuff on this side [link](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Test-Selection-Language) is for the console/terminal, right? So I can't write it like in the old example in my question?

Comment: Correct.  The reasoning being (I believe) is that the old way is too rigid in that it requires a code change to changed which tests are run.  The command line can provide the same functionality but is much easier to change.