# Can I run multiple nunit tests sequentially from command line?(using nunit console runner)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, command-line, nunit, nunit-console

I have a text file with list of test names. I want to run those tests in sequential order. Is there any command to use?

I have used --testlist option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use test suite in NUnit 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955854/how-to-use-test-suite-in-nunit-3)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to execute the console multiple times, specifying one test each time.

The --testlist option creates a filter, which selects the tests, but does not control the order of their execution. To control the order would require a new option as well as new internal parameters to be passed to the framework itself.